# Converting emoji from hex code to unicode

Tags: unicode, emoji

I want to use emojis in my iOS and Android app. I checked the list of emojis [here](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) and it lists out the hex code for the emojis. When I try to use the hex code such as `U+1F600` directly, I don't see the emoji within the app. I found one other way of representing emoji which looks like `\uD83D\uDE00`. When using this notation, the emoji is seen within the app without any extra code. I think this is a Unicode string for the emoji. I think this is more of a general question that specific to emojis. How can I convert an emoji hex code to the Unicode string as shown above. I didn't find any list where the Unicode for the emojis is listed.

Comment: Are you using Swift? If so, then `"\u{1f600}"` works fine. Same for modern JavaScript. For Java, `appendCodePoint` should work. Can you give us more info for what you are trying to do? Or are you looking for the general algorithm to convert code points to UTF-16?

Comment: `1F600` is full Unicode. `D83D DE00` is UTF-16 encoding of that Unicode. You can either use the full Unicode as RayToal's comment showed, or any Unicode to UTF-16 converter, or an Emoji table that lists UTF-16 such as https://punchdrunker.github.io/iOSEmoji/table_html/index.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your question is really one of "how do I display a character, knowing its code point?"

This question turns out to be rather language-dependent! Modern languages have little trouble with this. In Swift, we do this:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> "\u{1f600}"
$R0: String = ""
```

In JavaScript, it is the same:

```
$ node
> "\u{1f600}"
''
```

In Java, you have to do a little more work. If you want to use the code point directly you can say:

```
new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x1f600).toString();
```

The sequence `"\uD83D\uDE00"` also works in all three languages. This is because those "characters" are actually what Unicode calls *surrogates* and when they are combined together a certain way they stand for a single character. The details of how this all works can be found on the web in many places (look for UTF-16 encoding). The algorithm is there. In a nutshell you take the code point, subtract 10000 hex, and spread out the 20 bits of that difference like this: `110110xxxxxxxxxx110111xxxxxxxxxx`.

But rather than worrying about this translation, you should use the code point directly if your language supports it well. You might also be able to copy-paste the emoji character into a good text editor (make sure the encoding is set to UTF-8). If you need to use the surrogates, your best best is to look up a Unicode chart that shows you something called the "UTF-16 encoding."

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot. I was able to just use the unicode by using `\u{1f600}` as you mentioned in your context. I am using it in `react-native` which then passes the emoji code along to both Swift and Java and it worked on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi XE `#$1F600` is equivalent to `#55357#56832` or D83D DE04 smile.

Within a program, I use it in the following way:

```
const smilepage : array [1..3] of WideString =(#$1F600,#$1F60A,#$2764);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your input, I adjusted the typesetting for you.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript** - two way

```js
let hex = "".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
let emo = String.fromCodePoint("0x"+hex);

console.log(hex, emo);
```