# Convert long hex to unicode character such as emoji, programmatically

Tags: python, unicode

Given a variable containing the hex value of an emoji character as `str` (e.g., `s = '1f602'`), how to programmatically print that into a file as a UTF-8 encoded emoji character?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061358/converting-emoji-from-hex-code-to-unicode) doesn't do it programmatically, but requiring the code point itself to be included in the source code.

I know that this works **in Python 3 only**:

```
import codecs
s = '1f602'
with codecs.open('test.out', 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write('{}\n'.format(eval('u"{}{}"'.format(r'\U000', text))))
```

The file, when opened in a supported text editor, will show a single emoji character.

How to make this works also in Python 2, and without `eval`?

I thought `unichr` would work, but it only accept unicode characters less than `0x10000`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also go through UTF-32 encoding:

```
import struct

def fullchr(n):
    return struct.pack('<I', n).decode('utf-32le')

outfile.write(fullchr(0x1F602))   # int('1F602', 16)
```

Or from Python 3.3 onwards there is no longer such a thing as a narrow build, so you can just use `chr(0x1F602)`.

Comment: Right, I didn't realize you can simply do `chr(0x1F602)` in Python 3. What is this `struct` by the way?

Comment: It's a [stdlib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) that packs data into binary structures, a quick way here to pad an integer code point into a four-byte little-endian data structure which happens to be the same format as the UTF-32 encoding specifies.

Answer (score 1):

This works in both Python 2 and 3.  It uses the safer `ast.literal_eval` to build the character, since as you found, `unichr` won't work for characters above U+FFFF on a narrow Python 2 build.

```
import ast
import io

s = '1f602'
s2 = "u'\\U{:08X}'".format(int(s,16))
c = ast.literal_eval(s2)
with io.open('test.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(c)
```

Comment: So is there really no way to not use some sort of eval?

Comment: @justhalf Go with bobince's answer.  It's also portable but much faster.